# I get confused with git repos - FuelPHP project

Tags: git, fuelphp

I have a initial application setup and I have a basic directory structure.
Currently I'll use Fuel PHP Framework for my project and here is question come in

[image: see here the image]

Should I init repo in root directory (what includes framework souce as well) or in app directory(only specific application source code)? What the best approach?
I just got confused with.

I think that I should track only specific application code but I'm not sure. 
In Symfony I should create a repo under src/ directory but Fuel it's just badly arranged.

Comment: Don't put the framework in your git repo, just the composer file

Comment: You need the root directory, but you should exclude the dependencies downloaded by composer (and usually, composer.phar itself). Your .gitignore is probably a default that does this for you - what's in it?

Comment: @DaveMorrissey, You're right! I've been checking here and the default .gitignore list fuel/core, fuel/packages and fuel/vendor.
Post this comment as answear and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I joined to FuelPHP Forum and I've posted the same question. 
This question was answered by Harro Verton, FuelPHP Project Manager and Developer.

He wrote:

> The answer is (unfortunately); it depends.
>
> First question is, did you install from zip, or by cloning the
>   fuel/fuel repository (manual or through oil install)?
>
> If by zip, then you don't have a local repo, so you can just init a
>   new one in your installation root, and you'll have everything in one
>   single repository.
>
> You would do this, for example if you deploy your application as a
>   whole (for example using FTP), you don't have commandline access on
>   your production server, or your server doesn't have direct internet
>   access.
>
> If you want this but cloned the repo, you need to remove the .git
>   directories in fuel/core, and all fuel/packages, so that it becomes a
>   single repo. You will still have your installation root .git folder
>   (which is the fuel/fuel repo), so you need to change origin from
>   https://github.com/fuel/fuel to your own repository.
>
> If you do have commandline access and internet access, I would not use
>   the zip, but clone the fuel/fuel repo, and use composer to install the
>   rest of the framework. Don't remove the .git folders, only change the
>   origin to point to your repository.
>
> If you now push, you only push the fuel/fuel repo to your repository
>   (containing the app and any modules), but not the framework itself
>   (the core repo and all packages).

Post link: http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/comment/18373#Comment_18373

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with including the Symfony framework folder in your git repo *per se*, but it may be better to just put the folder containing your app files in the repo instead.

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP (just as anything that comes from the "outside world") should be treated as a vendor branch artefact.

I don't know Fuel so can't say which foldes are/are not part of it.